# Simple Build Tool: How do I know what versions of Scala and dependencies are available?

Tags: dependencies, sbt

I'm completely new to Simple Build Tool, so please pardon my beginner question.

I'm trying to setup SBT (version 0.10.1) to compile my Scala project. I got most things running and even changed some settings to fit my directory structure, etc. The most painful part in all of this was setting the exact versions of Scala and every library I use. For example (from my `build.sbt` file):

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.0" % "1.6.1"
```

How in the world am I supposed to know that Scala version must be "2.9.0-1" and not "2.9.0.1"? Is there any way to request all versions available? (I imagine the whole thing works more or less like repositories in Linux distributions, right?). Off course, it would also be very nice to know what else lives in those repositories.

So in conlusion, my question is this: **How do I request the contents of the repositories used by SBT?**

Comment: It must have something to do with http://search.maven.org/ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to know what Scala Versions are available you can take a look at the
[Scala Realeases Maven Repository](http://main.scala-tools.org/).

So your mentioned version is under:

- compiler
  h t t p://main.scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.9.0-1/
- library
  h t t p://main.scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9.0-1/

What Scala version your dependencies support can be answered in a similar way. In the Maven repository a Scala library can use the Scala version in the name, e.g. the Scalatest library looks like this:

- h t t p://main.scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.8.1/1.5.1/
- h t t p://main.scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.9.0/1.6.1/

The 1.6.1 version in only available for Scala 2.9.0 and 1.5.1 only for 2.8.1. **But I do not know about the compatibility between the versions, if a 2.8.1 library can be used with 2.9.0**